# Empty response when scraping things with scrapy (python)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrap a website ('ellenmacarthurfoundation') using scrapy and its `Selector.css`, specifically this page:

[Here's the website](https://www.ellenmacarthurfoundation.org/explore?sortBy=dateDesc&contentType=Article) 
[Here's the html of the web that I'm trying to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIwRH.png)

I'm trying to get all the references (<a href=new-url />) that are in this web, but I'm not able to get the different elements.

The code that I'm using is:

```py
>>> links = response.css('.section-container li.ais-InfiniteHits-item a::attr(href)').getall()
>>> links 
[]
```

I don't know why I'm receiving an empty answer. It will be great if anyone could helpe me with the string that I should use in order to get all the links.

Thanks you everyone!

Comment: Try to scrape the title first. Then, try to scrape the one-level deeper HTML element. Try to scrape the `li` elements. Try to scrape the `li` elements' href attributes. Oh, wait! They do not have a href attribute, maybe this could be your problem, right?

Comment: There's an `href` attribute inside the `<a>`. I've been debugging and I realized that, that part of the html isn't on my `response.text` so I believe that part loads dynamically. I'm trying to get all the links using `scrapy.linkExtractor`. I'll let you know if I get something. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Articles on this website load dynamically. You can't scrape this content in the usual way. You have selenium option but I suggest you send your find source api of this content in Inspect > Network > xhr:

[image: This is Firefox. You can find it in Chrome too.]

and extract data and headers from network part and scrape with POST request method like this:

```
>>> req = scrapy.Request(url, body=json_data, method='post', headers=headers) 
>>> fetch(req)
>>> response.json()
```